# Global sensitivity indices with sign (positive/negative)

Tags: nonlinear-regression, sensitivity-analysis, sobol-indices

I’ve used Sobol global sensitivity indices to analyze the effect that some input variables have on a nonlinear regression model, but now I need to know if the effect is positive or negative (i.e. if the output increases/decreases by increasing a given input variable). Is it possible to extend the Sobol global sensitivity indices to have positive and negative sign? Or are there other similar metrics to Sobol global sensitivity indices that can account for sign and magnitude?

Further details:

I have a nonlinear regression model $y = F(x_1, x_2, ... x_M)$, using the Sobol sensitivity indices I know which subset of input variables $x_1, x_2, ... x_N$ have the biggest influence on $y$, now I want know, which of those input variables do I need to increase in order to get an increase in $y$

Comment: Even for a univariate function, it is not clear what "effect is positive/negative" could mean unless the function is monotonic. Much more so if it is multivariate. I think you have to specify in detail what you really want. Maybe studying the gradient would be a start?

Comment: Thanks @g-g for the comment, I added some extra details. Maybe the gradient is a good idea